# Use Ajax handler with a form submitted by checkbox 'onchanged' event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to convert a form submission to jQuery's Ajax. The page holds a product filter (by Price,type) and product names - each row has a form with a checkbox where the onchanged property is submitting the form:

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="" name="pfilter" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

Can anybody let me know, how to achieve this by ajax.

I tried below code

```
 $("form").live('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myContainer").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
```

But products are not getting filtered.

Comment: Can you verify that the data is being sent and received correctly on the server.

Comment: Form is not even not getting submitted via ajax. It is getting submitted as on normal change event

Comment: Is the submit function above being called? event.preventDefault(); should stop the form from being submitted normally.

Comment: no error at all.. m figuring it out.. meantime if anybody can help me with code for jquery ajax submit on change

Comment: the form submit only via `this.form.submit` .. ajax call is not fired even after removing `preventDefault`

Comment: why use a form.submit..? just have a js handler with ajax upon clicking the submit button or whatever event you want to submit the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="page.php">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" name="pfilter" onchange="$('#form').submit();"/>
</form>
<script>
    $("#form").on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myContainer").html(data);
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using a newer version of jQuery so I'm using .on instead of .live